# Is it valid to use entries in #default_value if they are not in the #options?

Tags: forms

I have a form. On this form I have a select element, like this:

```
  array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Animals'),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array(
      'rat' => t('Rat'),
      'cat' => t('Cat'),
      'dog' => t('Dog'),
    ),
  );
```

I also have a function called `get_suggested_animals($user_id)`. Let's assume that this code works:

```
global $user;
print_r(get_suggested_animals($user->uid));

// Array
// (
//    [0] => lizard
//    [1] => cat
// )
```

Would it be OK to just write:

```
array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Animals'),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array(
      'rat' => t('Rat'),
      'cat' => t('Cat'),
      'dog' => t('Dog'),
    ),
    '#default_value' => get_suggested_animals($user->uid),
  );
```

without testing if default options are on the list of available ones? I know it works (in this example - only 'cat' is selected by default), it does not generate any warnings or anything, but I still feel uncertain if it's legit, or if there are hidden traps I simply don't know yet.

Comment: Just to confirm...are you trying to ascertain if an 'incorrect' default value (like "lizard" in this example) will just be thrown away by the FAPI, and if not, whether that value could potentially linger somewhere to be used without your knowledge in processing the form later?

Comment: The comments on [`form_process_select()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_select/7) are interesting: _This process callback is mandatory for select fields, since all user agents automatically preselect the first available option of single (non-multiple) select lists._ It might suggest that "cat" being chosen for an invalid value is actually the browser's choice, not Drupal's. I know that's not a direct answer but I'm having trouble finding the right bit of the FAPI code to check for this

Comment: @Clive I have available values and default values selected by two unrelated functions, and I want to avoid calculation of a common part. Also, it works properly even if cat is not a first option. Also, "incorrect" value is actually perfectly valid, except it is not available for current user, or in current conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the code of [`form_process_select`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_select/7) it is obvious that the situation where `#default_value` is set, but the value isn't a valid option, is not being handled properly:

This piece of code may "fail" in that case:

```
// If the element is required and there is no #default_value, then add an
// empty option that will fail validation, so that the user is required to
// make a choice. Also, if there's a value for #empty_value or
// #empty_option, then add an option that represents emptiness.
if (($required && !isset($element['#default_value'])) || isset($element['#empty_value']) || isset($element['#empty_option'])) {
  $element += array(
    '#empty_value' => '',
    '#empty_option' => $required ? t('- Select -') : t('- None -'),
  );
```

In your sample code, you don't set `#required` for the select field. That is why you don't observe any effect.

However, in the general case, you can't supply a bogus value for `#default_value` and *always* be sure that theFAPI will treat it just the same as *not set* or *NULL* `#default_value`.

If change your example and set `#required` to `TRUE`, and `#multiple` to `FALSE`, you should be able to reproduce a situation where having a bogus default value (such as "lizard") behaves different from the default value being *NULL* or absent.

Comment: OK, so it'll work if I will not require that field, but may fail if field is required and none of default options supplied is a valid one, right? And only in this specific case?

Comment: @Mołot, I've haven't conducted a exhaustive code review. I read through the code until I spotted a use case were it would fail. I don't know if it is *only* in that case it will fail, nor do I care. That's enough to avoid the construct. You don't want to write code that works today, and then, two years down the line, you (or somebody else) makes an seemingly unrelated edit, and your program's behaviour changes.  It is easy enough to avoid: Just don't pass the preset default value if it is *not* one of the available options to the select.  FAPI knows how to deal with missing or `NULL` defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage in, garbage out applies -- if `#default_value` is not an `#options` who knows and also who cares what will get into the page. Quite likely nothing good will happen cos if memory serves it'll try to use `#default_value` as an array index into `#options` and that can't possible work. So a notice might happen and depending on what we put into `form_select_options` the option might or might not appear.

This is all totally irrelevant because if you actually submit a value that doesn't exist in `#options` (whether by messing up your form building code or tampering with `POST`) then you will get a validation error.

Comment: I agree with the GIGO part. But no validation error in Drupal 7.28 at least. (Yes, I've tested it).

Answer (score -1):

I would use something like the below:

```
  '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Animals'),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t(' - Select - '),
      'rat' => t('Rat'),
      'cat' => t('Cat'),
      'dog' => t('Dog'),
    ),
    '#default_value' => !empty($default = get_suggested_animals($user->uid)) ? $default : 0,
```

Using the ? and : in for #default value says that if the first condition is true (the default value is not empty), use that. Otherwise, default to 0 (the select option).

Comment: What would the point of this be?  If the default value is "lizard", it is *not empty*, so that would be used.  However, "lizard" is not in the list of legal options, so it presents a condition that FAPI (as it is currently implmented) is not always prepared to deal with.